# Making sure altering a function doesn't break code in rest of package

Tags: r

I have a package and am debating altering the code of a function.  I will but want to determine how that affects everything else.  I have this as a package on github and a local repo.  My initial thought was to list all the functions in the package (even ones that are not loaded in the namespace) and then some how send all those to the console.  Then I could cut and paste the code to a text editor and look for instances of this function being used.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's an easy solution to this problem.  If my way seems like the most reasonable I still don't know how to make that occur.

Comment: I've been trying to get you to use testthat for some time now...  This is one of the reasons for testing.

Comment: Ditto on the unit testing.  Also, RStudio has a grep-like feature that will search all the .R files in a directory, recursively if necessary.  So none of this copy/paste nonsense.

Comment: @Dason Well let's get cooking on `pacman` so you can show me ropes :)  Ari didn't know about that.

Comment: @TylerRinker I totally added like... 27 lines of code yesterday...  And there are already some tests in pacman.  You could start adding a few and I could give you feedback on them if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called unit testing. And while it is no panacea ("you cannot prove or test correctness") is helps a good deal.

See [this page at the R Wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=developers:runit) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly fast way to see what functions are affected by or contain other functions.  Recently, I found out I don't need `require` or `library` inside of package function when using imports.  So I looked through my package using that package's function `termco.a` to look for incidents with `library` or `require`.  The first part passes the path of your package R directory and reads in each file line by line.  Then `termoco.a` counts the occurrences and using indexing to return just those functions that contain those terms. You'll have to download the beta version of the package [`qdap`](https://github.com/trinker/qdap).

Installing `qdap`:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("qdap", "trinker")
```

Find terms:

```
WD <- getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/trinker/GitHub/qdap/R/")
m <- sapply(dir(), readLines)
n <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(m), function(i){
    data.frame(fun=rep(names(m)[i], length(m[[i]])), text=m[[i]])
}))

x <- with(n, termco.a(text, fun, qcv(require, library)))
x$raw[rowSums(x$raw[, -c(1:2)]) > 0, ]
```

Output:

```
> x$raw[rowSums(x$raw[, -c(1:2)]) > 0, ]
                   fun word.count require library
1   adjacency_matrix.R        198       0       1
59         formality.R        954       2       0
112            qprep.R        145       4       4
116  read.transcript.R        563       1       1
144         termco.a.R        614       1       0
146         termco.d.R        535       1       0
156      trans.cloud.R        928       5       0
```